# Representation matrix of quotient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $V$ be $n$ dimensional vector space.
Let $A$ be a representation matrix of linear map $f$ between $V$ and $V$.

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$.

Suppose $A$ is not diagonalizable, then is there $W$ such that induced linear map $f'$ between $V/W$ and $V/W$ be diagonizable?

I think Eigen space of $W$ satisfies the condition, but I don't know other subspace satisfies the contain..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $W=V$ would certainly work, but other than that such a subspace $W$ need not exist because $W$ would need to be $f$-invariant and it might happen that $V$ doesn't have any non-trivial invariant subspace.

Comment: $W=V$, or when $W$ has codimension $1$.